# Unexpected out - Finding Maximum and Second Maximum

Tags: c, data-structures, runtime-error, tournament

I am trying to implement a simple tournament in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int tourn[100], n, i;
    printf("Give n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n n = %d \n", n);
    for(i = n; i <= (2*n)-1; i++)
        scanf("%d", &tourn[i]);
    build(tourn, n);
    printf("\n Max = %d \n",tourn[1]);
    printf("\n Next Max = %d \n",nextmax(tourn, n));
 }

 void build(int tourn[], int n) {
    int i;
    for(i = 2*n-2; i > 1; i = i-2)
        tourn[i/2] = max(tourn[i], tourn[i+1]);
  }  

 int nextmax(int tourn[],int n) {
    int i = 2;
    int next;
    next = min(tourn[2], tourn[3]);
    while(i <= 2*n-1) {
        if(tourn[i] > tourn[i+1]) {
            next = max(tourn[i+1], next);
            i = 2*i;
        }
        else {
            next = max(tourn[i], next);
            i = 2*(i+1);
        } 
    }
    return(next);
}

int max(int i,int j) {
    if(i > j)
        return i;
    else
        return j;
}                       

int min(int i,int j) {
    if(i < j)
        return i;
    else
        return j;
}
```

The output for `n = 5` and 
1 2 3 4 5

is 
 Max = 4195048

Next Max = 32588

and this output varies each time by a small amount!

if I place a test printf command before the build function, it doesn't execute.

Can someone find the error/explain the output? 
Thanks :)

Comment: You should explain what problem your code is trying to solve, and how it's trying to solve it.

Comment: Please indent your code properly and try to find an informative title

Comment: i think program find max element and next max element from user give input right.So obviously output will differ every time if user enter different value.Same output you will get if you enter same value each time.

Comment: Which output do you get for which input and what output do you expect ?

Comment: `I place a test printf command before the build function, it doesn't execute.` obviously not compile. and `this output varies each time by a small amount!` how much amount varies:)

Comment: The program is trying to find the max and second maximum of a given set of integers. I am using a crude data structure to solve it. The exact same code is working fine now! but .. yesterday, they were giving random output values like the one I had mentioned. Any idea why that might have happened?

Comment: @ajay Improving indentation is great, but you really shouldn't be changing the code (return types), even if you believe that that won't change what the code does.

Comment: @MichaelWalz The expected output for n=5 and 1 2 3 4 5 is Max - 5 and Nmax - 4.

Comment: @Dukeling It didn't have a return type (`build` function), and looking at the code, I thought the OP meant a `void` type. You're right, I shouldn't really be changing OP's code.

Comment: @ramcha for me it's working i got output 5 and 4 for n=5

Comment: @JKB .. I know I could be more clear but.. The code is working for me too now!.. but It showed these weird junk values yesterday.. Any idea out of experience as to why such an output would come?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems pretty broken to me. you don't mind to address beyond your array boundaries, which is a good way of producing random results:

```
while(i <= 2*n-1){
        if(tourn[i]>tourn[i+1]){
                next = max(tourn[i+1],next);
                i=2*i;
        } else {  
                next = max(tourn[i],next);
                i=2*(i+1);
        } 
}
```

Your (logical) array is of size `2n`. if `i` reaches the "highest" value, you test `tourn[i + 1]`, which is `tourn[2n]`.

Comment: But i is being multiplied by 2 each time. It would never achieve the value 2n-1. only 2n-2 or 2n. For 2n-2 its fine. for 2n the loop terminates.

Comment: OK, that's true. Still I have bad feelings considering your code. You start with i == 2 (you look at values tourn[2] and tourn[3], then you evaluate (in some cases) i == 4, thereby evaluating tourn[4] and tourn[5]. In the next iteration you are using i == 8 or i == 10. What is in the cells you skip (6 and 7, or 6,7,8 and 9) ?

Comment: Having found the max. The code is only looking at those numbers that were previously compared with the maximum. The idea is that the next maximum must be one of these numbers.

Comment: mmmh, if you can have duplicate values, it'll go wrong. e.g. you start with `10, 10, 10, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1`. This is stored in `tourn[15] .. tourn[8]`. `tourn[7] .. tourn[4]` contains `10, 10, 1, 1`. `tourn[3] == 10, tourn[2] == 1` and `tourn[1] == 10`. Now you start with `next = min(tourn[2], tourn[3]) == 1` and enter the loop. In the first iteration, next remains 1 and i becomes 6. Then next becomes 10, and i becomes 14. In the last iteration next remains 10. If the original order of the numbers were 10, 8, 10, ..., you'd end up with `next == 8`.